# PHP Method, Objects

Tags: php

I have the following PHP code (below) but cannot seem to get it to run? I think I'm missing something simple like a function (?) or other type of code(s)? It should print: My Antonia: Willa Cather (5.99).

Error message:
Fatal error: Call to undefined method shopProduct::getProducer() in C:\Program Files (x86)

```
<?php
class shopProduct
{
    //class body
}
class ShopProductWriter
{
    public function write($shopProduct)
    {
        $str = "{$shopProduct ->title}: " . $shopProduct->getProducer() . " ({$shopProduct -> price})\n";
        print $str;
    }
}
// we can test it like this

$product1 = new ShopProduct("My Antonia", "Willa", "Cather", 5.99);
$writer   = new ShopProductWriter();
$writer->write($product1);
print "Author: {$product1->getProducer()}\n";
?>
```

Comment: So where is the method: `getProducer` defined?

Comment: This is kind of the problem - I've only just started learning methods, objects today and don't understand?

Comment: Well the method will remain undefined until you actually write it, same as passing all those strings to the shopProduct() class won't do anything with them unless you write something in a __construct() method to do something with them

Comment: [Demo](https://3v4l.org/7VSGc)

Comment: If you are learning objects and methods you should understand that you need to declare method `getProducer` in class `ShopProduct` before calling it. So declare it and the error will be gone.

Comment: Thank-you, I only managed to write half the code - missing all the public function information. This will help me alot in the next few days :)